# Remove a cloned form but leave the last remaining form in place

Tags: jquery

I've created a form that has a clone and remove button, if you click clone it clones the form, when i click remove it removes that form, so far so good.

Now for the tricky part, well i think it is...

When i click remove I want the div to remove but once there is only one remaining, I don't want that one to be able to be removed

Here's a jsfiddle of what i've got so far http://jsfiddle.net/vs8p5/5/

Here's the jquery

```
function updateClonedInput(index, element) {
$(element).appendTo("body").attr("id", "clonedInput" +  index);
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("id", "show_upload_image_link_" + index);
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("name", "kandibox_theme_hero_options[show_upload_image_link_" + index + "]");
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_" + index + "']; ?>");
$(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "show_upload_image_link_button_" + index);
}

$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(){
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
    var new_Input = $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone();
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);    
});
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();

    $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
})
});
```

Comment: There's a few improvements you can do to your code. Here's a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/eZvEL/2/

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning so every bit of code helps me understand it more, can you explain why your code is improved?

Comment: Sure. The first improvement I did, was sending a jQuery wrapped element to your `updateClonedInput` function, rather than wrapping it every time for each call. Second improvement was accessing the textbox using `:text` and `:button` rather than `:first-child` since that's ambiguous. You could go a step further and use specific classes. Third improvement was calling `.attr()` for the textbox only once and sending all the properties I want to set at once (A lot of jQuery functions support this feature). Finally I replaces `.parents()` with `.closest()`, but that's just personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just disabling the remove button the below hides the button when only one is remaining.

http://jsfiddle.net/6eaQ2/

I added the following to the button.remove click event

```
if ($('.clonedInput').length < 2)
{
    $('button.remove').hide();
}
```

and the following to button.clone click event

```
$('button.remove').show();
```

Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/6eaQ2/10/

Added below to the css

```
.remove{ display: none; }
```

Comment: I like the idea and it works well if you clone a form, if you don't clone a form and click remove by mistake it removes the original. It somehow needs to be disabled first, once it's cloned then it becomes enabled, if you get that sorted i'll accept it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vs8p5/20/

```
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(){

    if($('.clonedInput').length > 1) {
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();

        $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
            updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
        })
    }

});
```

Comment: damn, 21 secs faster... Deleted my answer, since its identical

Comment: Perfect, I'll accept it as answered once it lets me